# Fedora 25 : Software management fails to start

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm

From the **System settings** >> **System Administration**, starting **Software Management** fails to start.
with the message

> Failed to load system repo: failed loading RPMDB

### Some context

- After the OS completed installation, I installed some other software through `yum` and `dnf` CLI tools. None of them have any issue for installing / updating / removing any software.
- This was my first try to do this things from GUI components on this fresh OS.

FYI

`$ rpm --version
RPM version 4.13.0.1`

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This CLI command fixed it for me.

`sudo rpm --rebuilddb`

Comment: I'd suggest accepting your own answer so that the question is no longer listed among the *unanswered questions*. Welcome to [unix.se]! Here's your first upvote.